# how to find all the solutions to $z^2+z+1-i=0$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have one exercise that I can't understand at all. My teacher isn't replying, and I need to solve it before the deadline..

The exercise says use the second line formula (ABC-formula) to find the complex solutions for this equation: $$z^2+z+1-i=0$$

Can someone explain how I can do this? I can't find anything on the internet that takes this topic, not even in the book.

I have already tried to read about it, but got absolutely nothing.

Comment: It's a quadratic equation. Plug into the quadratic formula that you hopefully already know from the real case; it works here too. (The constant term is the complex number $1-i$).

Comment: It might be tricky to simplify $\sqrt{-3+4i}$ @HenningMakholm

Comment: @SakethMalyala: Indeed. But that would be a different question than this "I don't know where to start"-type post.

Comment: thanks for your answers, guys. Could someone show me a step-by-step guide for this? Would be much appriciated

Comment: You can try to factor the polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}[\text{i}]$ by applying a version of the Rational Root Theorem for Unique Factorization Domains.  Since $1-\text{i}$ has norm $2$, which is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\text{i}]$, the polynomial is either irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[\text{i}]$ or it has a root which is a unit $\pm1,\pm\text{i}$.  Clearly, $\text{i}$ is a root, so the other root is $-1-\text{i}$.

Comment: is there an online calculator that i can use to show me a step by step guide to this problem?

Comment: @Hanna Probably not at any more detail than the answers here. This problem involves two ideas 1) use the quadratic formula 2) represent complex numbers as complex exponentials in order to take the square root. The first step you're familiar with from previous math courses. The second technique is used so frequently in complex analysis that any decent intro textbook (e.g. Saff & Snider) will have a section on it.

If you do indeed find answers helpful here. Please upvote them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can try with $z=a+bi$ where $a,b$ are real. Or you can solve it as quadratic equation.

If you multiply it by 4 we get: $$ 4z^2+4z+1+3-4i=0$$

so $$(2z+1)^2= -3+4i = (1+2i)^2$$

so $$2z+1 = \pm (1+2i)$$

Comment: thanks for taking the time to give an answer. Can i ask why you use 4? And what about the qudratic formula?

Comment: I avoid quadratic equation formula by multiplying by 4. If you try to solve with that formula you will get the same.

Comment: that's the problem, the teacher wants me to use the quadratic equation formula. Your solution is great but not what im looking for, thanks anyway

Comment: When we derive that formula, we multiply $ax^2+bx+c=0$ with $4a$ at the begining...

Comment: could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

Compute the discriminant as 
\begin{equation}
 \Delta 
 =
 b^2 - 4ac 
 =
 (1)^2 - 4(1)(1-i)
 =
 1 - 4 + 4i = -3 + 4i
\end{equation}
Now write it in geometric form
\begin{equation}
 \Delta  = \vert \Delta  \vert e^{i \theta}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
 \Delta 
 =
 \sqrt{(-3)^2 + 4^2} = 5
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
 \theta = -\tan^{-1} \frac{4}{3} + \pi
\end{equation}
So 
\begin{equation}
 \Delta = 5e^{-i\tan^{-1} \frac{4}{3} + i\pi}
 =
 1 + 2i
\end{equation}
The square root of this will be 
\begin{equation}
 z_1 = \frac{-b - \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
 z_2 = \frac{-b + \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}
\end{equation}
i.e.
\begin{equation}
 z_1 = \frac{-1 - 1 - 2i}{2} = -1 - i
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
 z_2 = \frac{-1 + 1 + 2i}{2} = i
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

The quadratic formula gives$$ z = \frac{1}{2}\left(-1 \pm \sqrt{1 - 4(1-i)}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(-1\pm\sqrt{-3+4i}\right)$$

The issue is dealing with the square root. Rewriting the complex number in exponential form is a common way forward. Remember that $a+ib = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta$ is the polar angle specifying the point $a+ib$ on the unit circle. If you make sketch of $-3+4i$ and said angle, you ought to be able to solve for $$\theta = \arctan(-4/3) + \pi.$$ Then $$-3+4i = 5e^{i(\theta + 2\pi k)}$$ with $k$ integer to proceed. The extra $2\pi k$ is because the angle is not unique. We'll see that term doesn't matter for this problem, but in general, it can be important. Substituting this and raising to the $1/2$ power gives

$$ z = \frac{1}{2}\left(-1\pm\sqrt{5}e^{i(\theta/2 + \pi k)}\right)$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2}\left(-1\pm\sqrt{5}e^{i(\theta/2)}e^{i\pi k}\right)$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2}\left(-1\pm\sqrt{5}e^{i\theta/2)}\right)$$

In the last line, I drop the $e^{i\pi k} $ term, since it equals $1$ for $k$ even and $-1$ for $k$ odd. That is, no matter the $k$, we will still find two unique solutions. Now evaluate using Euler's formula.

$$ z = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{5}\left[\cos(\theta/2) + i\sin(\theta/2)\right]}{2} = -1-i, i $$

Answer (score 0):

Alt. hint: $\;z^2+z+1-i=(z^2+1)+(z-i)=(z-i)(z+i)+(z-i)=(z-i)(z+1+i)\,$.